# Why do I always get JSON Exception?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, exception

This Is my first time with parsing JSON data. I am using the Google knowledge graph api. I got the api working and I can get the JSON result. This is Google 's sample return data for a sample query which I'm using now for testing.

```
 {
  "@context": {
"@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
"goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
"resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
"detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
"EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
"kg": "http://g.co/kg"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
{
  "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
  "result": {
    "@id": "kg:/m/0dl567",
    "name": "Taylor Swift",
    "@type": [
      "Thing",
      "Person"
    ],
    "description": "Singer-songwriter",
    "image": {
      "contentUrl": "https://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmVDAhjhWnN2OWys2ZMO3PGAhupp5tN2LwF_BJmiHgi19hf8Ku",
      "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift",
      "license": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0"
    },
    "detailedDescription": {
      "articleBody": "Taylor Alison Swift is an American singer-songwriter and actress. Raised in Wyomissing, Pennsylvania, she moved to Nashville, Tennessee, at the age of 14 to pursue a career in country music. ",
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift",
      "license": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
    },
    "url": "http://taylorswift.com/"
  },
  "resultScore": 896.576599
}
  ]
}
```

So I want to parse it so that I can get the name, description,  detailed description. This is my code but I always seem to get the exception. Any ideas why?

```
try {
                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(gggg); 
                    JSONArray itemListElement = object.getJSONArray("itemListElement");
                    for(int i=0; i < itemListElement.length();i++){
                            JSONObject c = itemListElement.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject results = c.getJSONObject("result");
                            String name = results.getString("name").toString();
                            String description = results.getString("description").toString();
                            String detailedDescription = results.getString("articleBody").toString();
                            gggg = "Name: "+name+"\n Description: "+description+"\n "+detailedDescription;
                    }

                    responseView.append(gggg);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,gggg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Also the `string gggg` contains the JSON data. I don't know why but I am always getting the exception. Please tell me what is the error in my code and how to repair it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> "Name: Taylor Swift  Description: Singer-songwriter  Taylor Alison
>   Swift is an American singer-songwriter and actress. Raised in
>   Wyomissing, Pennsylvania, she moved to Nashville, Tennessee, at the
>   age of 14 to pursue a career in country music. "

The problem is your `String detailedDescription` line.

You need to get the detailedDescription object before you retrieve the articleBody.

```
for(int i=0; i < itemListElement.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = itemListElement.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject results = c.getJSONObject("result");
            String name = results.getString("name");
            String description = results.getString("description");
            JSONObject detailedDescription = results.getJSONObject("detailedDescription");
            String articleBody = detailedDescription.getString("articleBody");
            String x = "Name: "+name+"\n Description: "+description+"\n "+articleBody;
        }
```

Also your `.toString()` method calls are redundant as you are calling `.getString()` on the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

With in the android json library it has a method called has element, which returns true or false. After successfully checking then access the element.  The expection be caused by tring to access an element that isn't there.

Might be worth printing out  after each time you create a new object to ensure that the objects are being created. It will also piont to where the expection is happening.